# JQuery Validation is not working in save button click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have been trying for a few hours to make the validation work but to no avail. I have included name attribute in the input element. Script sources have been included too. Validate method has also been fired. The contents are not validated. Can anyone see what is wrong with my code? Thanks in advance.
Merry X'mas!

My Html Code

```
<input type="text" id="sessionSynopsisNameInput" name="sessionSynopsisNameInput" 
  class="form-control input-group-lg" maxlength="70" placeholder="Session Name" value=""/>
<div class="errMsg"></div>
```

My Javascript code

```
setupFormValidationRules();
function setupFormValidationRules() {
    jQuery.validator.addMethod('lettersonly', function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/.test(value);
    });

    $('#dataForm').validate({
        rules: {
            sessionSynopsisNameInput: {
                required: true,
                lettersonly: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            sessionSynopsisNameInput: {
                required: 'Please enter Session Synopsis Name',
                lettersonly: 'Only spaces and alphabets are allowed'
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The validate method is called in the save button click handler.

```
$('#saveButton').on('click', function () {
    $('#dataForm').validate();
});
```

These are the script sources that I have included

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/additional-methods.js"></script>
```

Comment: I would suggest to add required or letteronly attribute in input element

Comment: @R.S. that doesn't matter, in fact by this method we can define custom message too.

Comment: @R.S. in rules `sessionSynopsisNameInput` is id so it will validate for this id only

Comment: Ok got it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

**lettersonly** is already there in *additional methods* I have to change the name **lettersonly1** and it's working fine you can check in the example

```js
setupFormValidationRules();

function setupFormValidationRules() {      
    $.validator.addMethod('lettersonly1', function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[^-\s][a-zA-Z\s-]+$/.test(value);
    });

    $('#dataForm').validate({
        rules: {
            sessionSynopsisNameInput: {
                required: true,
                lettersonly1: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            sessionSynopsisNameInput: {
                required: 'Please enter Session Synopsis Name',
                lettersonly1: 'Only spaces and alphabets are allowed'
            }
        }
    });
}

$(function(){
    $('#dataForm').validate()
})

$("#dataForm").on("submit", function(){
    if($(this).valid()){
        console.log('submit');
        $(this).submit();
    }
    
    return false;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
<form method='post' action='#' id = 'dataForm'>
    <input type="text" id="sessionSynopsisNameInput" name="sessionSynopsisNameInput" 
      class="form-control input-group-lg" maxlength="70" placeholder="Session Name" value=""/>
    <div class="errMsg"></div>
    <button id='saveButton' name='saveButton' type='submit'>Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I am not sure why the form still allows me to post empty spaces. And even though lettersonly1 is invoked, but when I submitted the second time in that same page, it allows submission.

Comment: i have update my code please change the button type to submit if you have define it to button and change your form validate method to ready function please make changes and then check

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. Is not working. Error messages are shown but it still allows the empty spaces and values to be accepted..

Comment: then you need to change your regexp which should not accept space